# Eigenvalues of a matrix whose elements are given as the sum of the product of another matrix's eigenvalues times some real coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

The title is quite long but I wouldn't know how to explain this otherwise.

I have been working on this paper for quite some time, [https://www.sciencedirect.com/.../pii/0393044088900319](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0393044088900319?fbclid=IwAR2Igj_XFMBYKm7pz3PVzXpcmcl-O3Jq2W7adQBVIE5G6sc-CQATUxBwSQU), and I can't understand how equation (26) implies equation (27) (reference 9 is to a book called "The Theory of Matrices" by Gantmakher).

[The equations in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koMhb.jpg)

It seems to me that this comes from some Linear Algebra concept that I must have obviously forgotten and that I can't quite find without proper reference. I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Explain better the question, what is exactly?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Basically, I have a rectangular real matrix C whose coefficients are given by C^{kp} and the paper says that, given some conditions on C, I can write a new matrix in terms of the coefficients of C as M_{pq}'=\sum C^{ip}m_iC^{jq} whose eigenvalues m_i' will be between m_i and m_{i+1}. I'm not quite sure how the condition on the eigenvalues comes about!